What should I be aware of concerning wild boars as a tourist in Spain during mating season?
In less than 2 weeks, I'm going on my yearly vacation to Spain that I mentioned in other questions. Today, one of my relatives who is already there shared a picture of him and his partner encountering several wild boars. They were walking along a nearby road that's adjacent to a small protected wetlands area around an old salt mine, where we've in the past seen boar tracks and even heard wild boar sleeping, and at the entrance to the walking route in that wetlands area were three boars foraging. We've also seen videos on Facebook of boars foraging around the same area.
I live in a suburban area in Flanders and as such am not really familiar with wild animals beyond the occasional squirrel, rat, mouse or pigeon. Hence, I don't really know what to do or how to handle larger animals like this. I know that they can be surprisingly dangerous when provoked. I also know that the period when I'm there is right in the middle of mating season for wild boar, but I don't know to what extent that impacts their behavior.
What advice do you have for me regarding these animals?

This possibly might be better asked in The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange

Here are some recommendations. It does not sound like they are particularly dangerous animals, though they are certainly capable of causing harm if surprised, cornered or seriously injured (or if you threaten their young). 3 of the 4 boar-related deaths in the US in the past 150 years were as a result of an injured boar in a hunting situation. Maybe you'll find  jabalíes on the menu.
